# nullptr as default pointer-to-member function parameter passed to template function

Tags: c++

I would like to have a template function with a default pointer-to-member function parameter. I would expect that I could pass a `nullptr` as default value as it is has a valid conversion to pointer-to-member. And I would expect the template parameters to evaluate to `void` in this case. However this fails with:

`No instance of template matches the argument list`

Consider the following code:

```
template <typename ReturnT, typename TypeT, typename ArgT>
void function(ReturnT(TypeT::*member)(ArgT) = nullptr)
{
    if (member)
    {
        // Do stuff with member.
    }
    else
    {
        // Not do stuff with member.
    }
}

function() // Fails
```

I have tried providing `void` as default template parameters, but that does not work either. I know I could just overload `function` with an empty parameter list, but I'm wondering why this particular technique does not work as I expect.

---

**EDIT**
Ok, here is what I actually try to do. I'm trying to build one function that accepts two pointer-to-member function parameters. Based on which of them is set, I would like different behavior, using the specific type to which the members belong.

Something like this:

```
template <
    typename ReturnT,
    typename TypeT,
    typename ArgT
>
void function(
    ReturnT(TypeT::*getter)() = nullptr,
    ReturnT(TypeT::*setter)(ArgT) = nullptr
)
{
    if (getter)
    {
        // Set getter parameters using ReturnT and TypeT.
    }
    if (setter)
    {
        // Set setter paramters using ReturnT and TypeT.
    }
}
```

Comment: It's impossible for the compiler to deduce `ReturnT`, `TypeT` and `ArgT` from only `nullptr_t`. Why do you need to know these types if given a nullptr? What would you do with the deduced types?

Comment: If you say it like that it sounds quite logical haha. Altough I still would expect that if types can't be deduced, something like defaults would work. I have updated my question, but I see that I may have to rethink this one...

Comment: I think I'll just go with separate overloads.

Comment: You can always use default template parameters. `template <typename ReturnT = void ...>`